# MonteCarlo option pricing error estimate

Tags: option-pricing, monte-carlo

Consider the problem of pricing an option via MonteCarlo with 10000 simulations. If the variance of the simulation is 100, which is the MC estimate of the error on the price?

Comment: The confidence interval for the estimator $\hat{C}$ is given by $\hat{C}\pm z_{\alpha/2}\frac{s_C}{\sqrt{N}}$ where, in your case, $N=10,000$ and $s_C=10$.

Comment: The options for the answer are:
1) 0.001
2) 0.01
3) 0.1
4) 1
5) 0.0001

Comment: Based on your comment, I would say 0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the standard error, i.e. the simulation error, then this can be defined as:

$\frac{\hat{\sigma(M)}}{\sqrt{M}}$

where M is the number of simulations and  $\sigma$ is the estimated standard deviation $(\sqrt{\hat{\sigma^2}})$ of the specific simulation run. The “ $\hat{}$” denotes that it is the estimate.

I hope that this will help you.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks a lot

Comment: Happy to have helped please +1

Comment: I am quite new to this site, did I do what you asked?

Comment: Yeap all good ty